# Group Duplicates in different results depending on location in data set

Tags: sql

We would like to see how long a call has been with a department in our ticket system, we cannot use the min and max date from the call as the call can go to one department more than once:

A call can be with support , goes to branches and then come back to support so we cannot use min and max by group as it will show that the call has been with support the entire life cycle of the call.

I have a result that brings back the same information but for different times, I would like to group these into their own result

I have tried to use ranking but this didn't resolve the problem as the same rank applies to the value even when it is further down in the result set

```
select
min(update_time), max(update_time) ,assigned_group,version,update_time,
datediff(HOUR,min(update_time), max(Update_time)) as difference ,
 dense_rank() Over (partition by assigned_group order by  version ) as 
 pDenserank,
 rank() Over (partition by assigned_group order by version) as prank,
 dense_rank() Over (order by assigned_group) as denserank,
 rank() Over (order by assigned_group) as rank,
 assign_counter
 from service_req_history
 where id = 405012
 group by   version, assign_counter,update_time , 
assigned_group,version,update_time
order by assign_counter]
```

[Current Result Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TorA8.jpg)

I would like to see the following Results: Please see attached file

```
Min Update Time Max Update Time      assigned_group Days with Department
2019/07/19 16:28    2019/07/22 09:01 Support        3
2019/07/22 11:32    2019/08/26 13:25 Branches       4
2019/08/26 15:44    2019/08/28 11:22 Support        2
2019/08/28 11:47    2019/08/28 15:32 Technical      0
```

[Expected result Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdUXF.png)

Your input would be highly appreciated, thanking you in advance.
Regards Charl

Comment: Sample data would really help.

Comment: Hi Gordon, please see the  hiperlink in the comment section "Expected Result" and "Current Result"

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking table.

Answer (score 0):

To start with you might want to do something as below:

```
SELECT MIN(update_time) 'Min Update Time'
    ,MAX(update_time) 'Max Update Time'
    ,assigned_group
    ,SUM(Call_Duration)/60.0/24 AS 'Days with Department'
FROM (
      SELECT LAG(update_time) OVER(ORDER BY update_time ASC) prev_update_time
            ,update_time
            ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE, LAG(update_time) OVER(ORDER BY update_time ASC), Update_time) AS 'Call_Duration'
            ,assigned_group             
      FROM service_req_history
      WHERE id = 405012
    ) AS CallDurationSet
GROUP BY assigned_group
```

To get other id's, you may want to remove the `WHERE` clause and add "`id`" column in the  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution however, grouping will work if the call stayed with one department and then moved onto another, but seeing that it can go back and forth between departments it includes days that it was actually with another department example: Call with support on 1st of jan, escalated to technical on the 5th of jan and then back to support on the 6th of jan, so by grouping it that way it will show that the call was with support from the 1st to the 5th, however I want to see the call was with support 5 days and then back to technical for 1 day and then again for 1 day.

Comment: Just changed the query for it to work if call transfers across departments. You may want to change the datediff to seconds and modify Days with Department accordingly for more accurate results.